# 2sxc 8.08 to 8.11 lost my content after upgrade

Tags: 2sxc

I upgraded to 2sxc 8.11 from 8.08. None of my content is showing. Going back to 8.08 does not fix the problem. My entire site was built on this so I'm completely down.

Of course my content and images are all in the directory structure but my site is gone.

I know this is something simple. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to help ATM because your question is fairly open and there is no known bug that would do this. Just fyi: in 8.9/10/11 we added various features, but none should have such an effect. So I'm guessing it's something specific to your install.

So the quick fix: I would roll-back a backup to be online quickly. Then try an upgrade again on a copy to see if it still does this.

If you do want to try to corner the issue, my core question is: 
Are you content-items still in the admin-section, are are they completely gone?

Because it's a big difference if they are "deleted" or if they just don't show on the module-instances which should show them.